# Is it possible to specify a conda config into an environment file?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I use [environment files](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) to create new conda environments.

Unfortunately, my current project depends on the [free channel](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/free-channel.html), which has been removed from the default channel in newer versions of anaconda. It can be enabled by calling

```sh
    conda config --set restore_free_channel true
    # More generally, a config is set by:
    # conda config --set <key> <value>
```

This modifies the user's `~/.condarc`. Since this may have side-effects, I would like to add this config to the environment file, instead of globally setting the conda configs. Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to add the `free` channel like you would any other, without changing my config:

```
name: test-env
channels:
  - free
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=2.*
  - beautiful-soup
```

Output of `conda list -n test-env`:

```
# packages in environment at ****/opt/miniconda3/envs/test-env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
beautiful-soup            4.3.2                    py27_0    free
certifi                   2016.2.28                py27_0    free
openssl                   1.0.2l                        0    free
pip                       9.0.1                    py27_1    free
python                    2.7.13                        0    free
readline                  6.2                           2    free
setuptools                36.4.0                   py27_1    free
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0    free
tk                        8.5.18                        0    free
wheel                     0.29.0                   py27_0    free
zlib                      1.2.11                        0    free
```

Specifying the channel for a particular package also works:

```
name: test-env
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=2.*
  - free::beautiful-soup
```

Output of `conda list -n test-env`:

```
# packages in environment at ****/opt/miniconda3/envs/test-env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
beautiful-soup            4.3.2                    py27_0    free
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0  
certifi                   2019.11.28               py27_0  
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
ncurses                   6.2                  h0a44026_0  
pip                       19.3.1                   py27_0  
python                    2.7.17               h97142e2_0  
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
setuptools                44.0.0                   py27_0  
sqlite                    3.31.1               ha441bb4_0  
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
wheel                     0.33.6                   py27_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3
```